# Comparing two arrays and common objects add to new array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I got this code:

```
var counter = 0,
randoms = [],
randoms1 = [],
n;

for (n = 0; n < 5; n++) {
randoms.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 49 + 1));
randoms1.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 49 + 1));
}
```

With these 2 arrays how can I check if there is a common number in them, and this number add it to a new array?

Comment: First simple approach that comes to mind: For each element in `randoms`, iterate over `randoms1` and compare the values.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885557/simplest-code-for-array-intersection-in-javascript/1885569#1885569

Comment: @Rhumborl im not talented in searching, not even close to searching a topic named like that lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop over one of the arrays and check:

```
var matches = [];
for (var i = 0; i < randoms.length; i++) {
    if (randoms1.indexOf(randoms[i]) > -1) matches.push(randoms[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

--> Simple and heavy checking : Double `for` loop .
--> Harder but smarter and a bit lighter : use `(indexOf(smthg) > -1)`

--> My favorite :

```
randoms = [];

//Populating
for (var n = 0; n < 5; n++) {
randoms[Math.floor(Math.random() * 49 + 1)] = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 49 + 1));
}

//Checking
for (var n in randoms) {
if (randoms[randoms[n]]) console.log("Found One !");
}
```